Create a new package java in VS Code
I'm a beginner in java. I have installed all extensions to VSCode, but I cannot find the option to create a new java package
Options that shows for me:

I installed all the extensions, but can't find the option to create new java package. Only the ones in the photo.

A package in the actual file system of java is just a folder. As such, pressing new folder and saving your java files in there with the correct notation in them should hopefully work for you.

Right click on the project name under the JAVA PROJECTS panel and select New --> Package...

